# Why does Qt c++ app not throw exception on instantianting an attribute on object that does not have it?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I'm developing an app on QtDesigner.I've Promoted few QPushButtons to MyButton.
MyButton simply extends QPushButton and add to it an int attribute.
Working on the project I noted I forgot to promote one of my QPushButton so a I started to wander why does my code still work though I've set the attribute on an object that does not own it.
The object's attribute is set by casting a QPushButton pointer to MyButton Pointer.

```
((MyButton*) ui->btnScreen)->intAttribute = 11;
cout << ((MyButton*) ui->btnScreen)->intAttribute << endl;
```

I get no error and on the console I get

```
11
```

So, this means that I'm not doing a cast on the pointer but directly on the Object?

ADDED

Let's say I've ClassA and ClassB which extends the ClassA.

```
int main(int arg,char** argv)
{
   ClassA a;
   ClassB *pB;
   pB = (ClassB *) &a;
   pB->foo();
   return 0;
}

class ClassA{
   public:
    ClassA(){}
};


class ClassB : public ClassA {
 public:
    void foo(){
        cout<<"HELLO"<<endl;
    }
};
```

Why do I not get SIGSEGV Exception instead of the HELLO printed out?

Comment: What is `MyButton`? And by casting you say that `ui->btnScreen` *is* a pointer to a `MyButton` object, so if `MyButton` have a public member variable named `intAttribute` why shouldn't it work?

Comment: And please don't use C-style casting, it should be seen as a sing that you make something wrong. Use e.g. [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) instead , as in `static_cast<MyButton*>(ui->btnScreen)`. (Or possibly [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast))

Comment: ui->btnScreen is the button I forgot to promote to MyButton, so it's still of type QPushButton and should not own the intAtribute

Comment: Infact I get the warning "use of old style cast"

Comment: If by "promote" you mean the cast, then you do the casting in the code you show... Where do you forget to do this "promotion"?

Comment: In QtDesigner IDE you can promote widgets to class that extend it to be able to sue them in a DragAndDrop style, before the lines I've shown for sure ui->btnScreen is of QPushButton Type

Comment: So `ui->btnScreen` isn't *really* pointing to an `MyButton` object? Then what you're doing is [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). If you use `dynamic_cast` instead of the C-style cast then it would result in a null pointer.

Comment: I suspect you're invoking undefined behaviour.  You're telling the compiler `ui->btnScreen` if of type `MyButton*` when it isn't -- anything can happen.